# Hibernate filter in subclass

Tags: hibernate, filter, subclass, hbm, joined-subclass

I have super model **Animal** that have sub classes like  **Cat** and **Dog**.
I define *Cat* and *Dog* subclass with discriminator in hbm file. Now i wanna load all **Animal** and enable hibernate filter via dao but each sub classes have different filter condition.

**sample hbm file**

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class discriminator-value="type" name="Animal" table="Animal" >

          <discriminator column="discriminator" type="string" not-null="true" />
          <property name="name" column="name" type="string" not-null="true" />

          <subclass discriminator-value="cat" name="Cat">
            <property name="a" column="cat_a" type="string"  />
          </subclass>
          <subclass discriminator-value="dog" name="dog">
            <property name="b" column="dog_b" type="string"  />
          </subclass>

          <filter name="animal_filter" condition="..."/>

        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

has hibernate filter definition for each sub class and joined subclass?
Is there replacement solution?